# error UIBarButtonItem isOn

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, uiswitch

I'm using UISwitch in Navigation Bar where I'm trying to change query using UISwitch . 
I'm trying my code but every time it runs , there is an error 
`UIBarButtonItem isOn`.
I have no clue how can I solve the issue . 
I'm using the following code

```
@IBOutlet weak var barSwitch: UISwitch!
var query =  PFQuery(className: "mainClass")  


 func switchChanged(barSwitch:UISwitch){

if (barSwitch.on == true) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ () -> Void in

      self.query = PFQuery(className: "recentClass")

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
) }
    else   {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ () -> Void in

        self.query = PFQuery(className: "mainClass")

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print("button was pressed")

        }
    ) }

  }


 override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

switchChanged(barSwitch)

if (objects?.count == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
   }

    query.orderByAscending("SNo")

    return query
}
```

Comment: What do you want to say with `UIBarButtonItem isOn`? It's not in the code

Comment: I'm getting this error

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem isOn]

Comment: Are you sure that you linked your UISwitch to the outlet? That error happens if you call the isOn message to an object where you only think it's an UISwitch but really it's an UIBarButtonItem. You can also check in debugger what class your object has

Comment: I'm using UISwitch in navigation bar therefore , it is showing as UIBarButtonItem .